# Проблема с временем исполнения программы set, с++

Tags: c++, c++11

Всем привет.
Сделал маленькую прогу по добавлению и проверке синонимов для курса Яндекса. Как раз контейнер set прохожу.
Задание тут [Ссылка на задание курса](https://www.coursera.org/learn/c-plus-plus-white/programming/WRbZE/sinonimy) если вдруг важно.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
void Count_sin(const set<set<string>>& sinon, const string& word) {
    int key = 0;
    for (const auto& z : sinon) { //роемся в "большом" множестве
        for (const auto& y : z) { //и в каждом слове "маленького" множества
            if (y == word) { //ищем совпадение со словом, и если нашли
                key++; //плюсанули себе за то что нашли
            }
        }
    }
    cout << key << endl; //выводим сколько раз плюсанули себе 
}
void Check_sin(const set<set<string>>& sinon, const string& word1, const string& word2) {
    set<string> sett = { word1, word2 }; //создаем из слов "маленькое" множество
    int key = 0; //объявили ключ для проверки наличия синонима
    for (const auto& z : sinon) { //в каждом множестве "большого" множества
        if (z == sett) { //ищем совпадение
            cout << "YES" << endl; //и если нашли, то пишем ДА
            key++; //плюсанули себе
        }
    }
    if (key == 0) { //если не плюсанули себе, то
        cout << "NO" << endl; //пишем НЕТ
    }
}
int main() {
    int i;
    string comand, word1, word2;
    set<set<string>> sinon; //создадим "большое" множество "маленьких" множеств
    cin >> i; //количество строк запросов
    for (i; i > 0; i--) {
        cin >> comand; //считываем команду
        if (comand == "ADD") { //проверяем какая команда пришла
            cin >> word1 >> word2; //считываем слова
            sinon.insert({ word1, word2 }); //вставляем слова в "большое" множество
        }
        else if (comand == "COUNT") {
            string word;
            cin >> word; //считываем слово
            Count_sin(sinon, word); //узнаем сколько синонимов у слова
        }
        else if (comand == "CHECK") {
            string word1, word2;
            cin >> word1 >> word2; //считали слова
            Check_sin(sinon, word1, word2); //проверяем, есть ли такая пара
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

На одном из его тестов прога выполняется дольше 1 секунды. (Failed case #8/16: time limit exceeded (Time used: 1.99/1.00)) Нужно не более 1 секунды. На простых тестах отрабатывает быстро (менее 0,04 сек). Где может быть потеря времени, и почему?

**Новый код:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
using namespace std;        
int main() {
    int i, key;
    string comand, word1, word2, word;
    set<set<string>> sinon;
    cin >> i;
    for (i; i > 0; i--) {
        cin >> comand;
        if (comand == "ADD") {
            cin >> word1 >> word2;
            sinon.insert({ word1, word2 });
        }
        else if (comand == "COUNT") {
            cin >> word;
            key = 0;
            for (auto& z : sinon) { //ссылка есть
                key += z.count(word); //и функция
            }
            cout << key << endl;
        }
        else if (comand == "CHECK") {
            cin >> word1 >> word2;
            if (sinon.count({word1, word2})){ //и тут функция
                cout << "YES" << endl;
            }
            else cout << "NO" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Все равно долго считает. Уже не знаю что делать.

**Само задание...**

Два слова называются синонимами друг друга, если они имеют похожие значения. Реализуйте следующие операции над словарём синонимов:
ADD word1 word2 — добавить в словарь пару синонимов (word1, word2).
COUNT word — узнать количество синонимов слова word.
CHECK word1 word2 — проверить, являются ли слова word1 и word2 синонимами. Слова word1 и word2 считаются синонимами, если среди запросов ADD был хотя бы один запрос ADD word1 word2 или ADD word2 word1.

Формат ввода

Сначала вводится количество запросов Q, затем Q строк с описаниями запросов. Гарантируется, что в каждом запросе CHECK и ADD слова word1 и word2 различны. Все слова состоят лишь из латинских букв, цифр и символов подчёркивания.

Формат вывода

Для каждого запроса в соответствующей строке выведите ответ на него:
В ответ на запрос COUNT word выведите единственное целое число — количество синонимов слова word.
В ответ на запрос CHECK word1 word2 выведите строку YES, если word1 и word2 являются синонимами, и NO в противном случае.

**Итоговое решение**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
using sorted_pair = pair<string, string>;
sorted_pair make_sorted_pair(const std::string& word1, const string& word2) {
    return (word1 <= word2) ? make_pair(word1, word2) : make_pair(word2, word1);
}
bool check(const set<sorted_pair>& synonyms, const string& word1, const string& word2) {
    return synonyms.count(make_sorted_pair(word1, word2)) != 0;
}
void add(set<sorted_pair>& synonyms, map<string, unsigned>& synonyms_count, const string& word1, const string& word2) {
    if (check(synonyms, word1, word2)) return;  // синоним уже есть
    ++synonyms_count[word1];
    ++synonyms_count[word2];
    synonyms.insert(make_sorted_pair(word1, word2));

}
int main() {
    set<sorted_pair> synonyms;  // пары синонимов  
    map<string, unsigned> synonyms_count;  // количество синонимов
    int i;
    string comand, word1, word2;
    cin >> i; //количество запросов
    for (i; i > 0; i--) {
        cin >> comand; //считываем комманду
        if (comand == "ADD") { //проверяем какая комманда пришла
            cin >> word1 >> word2; //считываем слова
            add(synonyms, synonyms_count, word1, word2);
        }
        else if (comand == "COUNT") {
            string word;
            cin >> word; //считываем слово
            cout << synonyms_count[word] << endl;
        }
        else if (comand == "CHECK") {
            string word1, word2;
            cin >> word1 >> word2; //прочитали слова

            if (check(synonyms, word1, word2)){
                cout << "YES" << endl; //пишем Да
            }
            else cout << "NO" << endl; //иначе НЕТ
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да, действительно получается быстрее. 
Но все равно не проходит.

Comment: Чтобы посмотреть полное задание, требуется записаться на курсы :( Вы бы не могли его привести тут? Чтобы не оказалось, что мы пытаемся решить, как лучше держать микроскоп для забивания гвоздя...

Comment: Добавил описание задания

Comment: Вы не пробовали использовать `multimap`? Как по мне, прямо просится сюда...

Comment: Нет не пробовал multimap. Обошелся обычным. Решение дописал в текст вопроса. Всем спасибо. Каждому ответил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По условию задачи Вам надо две структуры данных:

```
using sorted_pair = std::pair<std::string, std::string>;
std::set<sorted_pair> synonyms;  // пары синонимов  
std::map<std::string, unsigned> synonyms_count;  // количество синонимов
```

Проверка синонима - это

```
sorted_pair make_sorted_pair(const std::string& word1, const std::string& word2) {
  return (word1 <= word2) ? std::make_pair(word1, word2) : std::make_pair(word2, word1);
}

bool check(const std::string& word1, const std::string& word2) {
  return synonyms.count(make_sorted_pair(word1, word2)) != 0;
}
```

Добавление:

```
void add(const std::string& word1, const std::string& word2) {
  auto r = synonyms.insert(make_sorted_pair(word1, word2));
  if (r.second) return;  // синоним уже есть
  ++synonyms_count[word1];
  ++synonyms_count[word2];
}
```

И количество - это просто `synonyms_count[word]`.

---

Если строки невероятно длинны, то в `synonyms` надо хранить не сами строки, а указатели на элементы `synonyms_count`. Элементы `set` и `map` не перемещаются при добавлении других элементов, значит не перемещаются и сами указатели.

```
using map = std::map<std::string, unsigned>;
using sorted_pair = std::pair<map::value_type*, map::value_type*>;
map synonyms_count;
std::set<sorted_pair> synonyms;
void add(const std::string& word1, const std::string& word2) {
  auto iter1 = synonyms_count.find(word1);
  auto iter2 = synonyms_count.find(word2);
  if (iter1 == synonyms_count.end()) iter1 = synonyms_count.emplace(word1, 0).first;
  if (iter2 == synonyms_count.end()) iter2 = synonyms_count.emplace(word2, 0).first;

  auto r = synonyms.insert(make_sorted_pair(&*iter1, &*iter2));
  if (r.second) return;  // синоним уже есть
  ++iter1->second;
  ++iter2->second;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Решение немного изменил, но суть вы правильно подсказали. Самая ошибка моя была , что пытался массив массивов перебрать. Особо тяжко проходил запрос COUNT. Самое верное решение - разделить на map и set. Тогда не нужно перебирать всё и поиск быстрее происходит. 
Плюсану чуть позже пройдет когда репутацию сделаю.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте функции-члены set, а не циклы для поиска.
Ваши циклы ищут совпадение за линейное время, 
тогда как встроенные средства set будут делать это за логарифм.

Comment: Самый простой вариант для проверки - `sinon.count(sett) > 0;`. Для ускорения можно ещё `unordered_set` использовать

Answer (score 1):

Быстрее, чем за линию обойти все set не получится(тебе нужно посмотреть на каждый).
Попробуй for (auto & z : sinon). Без ссылки каждое z будет копироваться, а на это будет уходить доп время.

---

UPD:
Попробуй выводить через printf. cout содержит много разных проверок, поэтому работает медленнее. Также, вместо i--(аналогично для инкремента) лучше использовать --i(i-- создает новую переменную и возвращает ее, а --i уменьшает собственное значение и его же возвращает).

Comment: Попробовал, не дало эффекта. Чего же я не понимаю?

Comment: @Acmades не зная условий задачи, нельзя точно сказать как лучше оптимизировать. По ссылке выше требует регистрации. Увольте. :)

Comment: За подсказку с инкрементом отдельное спасибо.